# Undo in vs code after closing and open again vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

**How to undo vs code changes after closing the vs code and open again**
I tried many time control **z and control y** to make change but it stucked.

Comment: Vs code has not such feature yet. You can undo the actions of previous sessinon after closing vs code.

Comment: Actually bro i was using autosave that's why

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible.

However, there is another way to achieve the same result with some preparation: put your code in a [`git` repository](https://git-scm.com/), and before making changes `commit` your work. Then if you find you want to roll back changes to a previous `commit` point, just use `git checkout`.

Comment: i was not linked with it.

Comment: Re "not possible" -- that's totally true in terms of VS Code's current features (you cannot currently do this using VS Code). But just to clarify: restoring undo history after the editor closes and reopens is something other editors ([like Vim/Neovim](https://neovim.io/doc/user/undo.html#undo-persistence)) can already do. So it would technically be possible for VS Code to add this feature at some point.